# Semipositive definite and hermiticity implication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, hermitian-matrices

Its something that is in all basic algebra books that, a semipositive definite operator is Hermitian and the eigenvalues of this hermitian operator are positive.

But I couldn't find any place where this relation is explained. How can one demonstrate that a semipositive operator imply hermiticity?

$$\langle v |A |v\rangle \geq 0 \quad  \forall |v\rangle \quad \stackrel{}{\Rightarrow} \quad A=A^{\dagger} $$

Where $A$ and $|v\rangle$ are elements of a Hilbert space of finite dimension i.e. complex matrix elements etc.

This is asumed in lot of books but I couldn't find it anywhere. If sameone could help me how to start, because I tried to prove the negation also but I don't arrive to any place.

Comment: I suspect $A$ is either a complex matrix over an operator over a complex inner product space. Please [edit] your question so that you state what kinds of objects $A$  and $|v\rangle$ are explicitly.

Comment: The conclusion is true in complex spaces. Try to analyze expression of the form $$\langle A(v+zw), v+zw\rangle ,$$ where $z$ is a complex coefficient.

Comment: Okay, I see more or les where to go, i supose I need to probe it for a $z$ that redirect us to $A=A^{\dagger}$. Chosing $z$ simplify the things,$$z=\frac{\langle A w|v\rangle}{|\langle A w|v\rangle|^2}$$ That as $|\langle A w|v\rangle|^2=\langle A w|v\rangle \langle A^{\dagger}v|w\rangle$ we get the expression $$\langle A v|v\rangle+|z|^2 \langle A w|w\rangle+ \frac{\langle A w|v\rangle\langle Av|w\rangle}{\langle Aw|v\rangle\langle A^{\dagger} v|w\rangle}+\frac{\langle A^{\dagger} v|w\rangle\langle Aw|v\rangle}{\langle A w|v\rangle\langle A^{\dagger} v|w\rangle}\geq 0$$ So how can i continue?

Comment: @Euler In what way does that choice of $z$ "simplify the things"?

Comment: Okay, I arrived to the conclusion that it doesn't make sense. I think I almost have it, I will answer my own question with the correct demonstration when I have it

Comment: Try $z=1$ and  $z=i $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that two operators $A,B$ are equal if and only if we have $\langle v|A |v\rangle = \langle v|B|v\rangle$ for all $|v\rangle \in H$. You can reach this conclusion by considering the expression $\langle v|(A - B)|v \rangle$ with $|v \rangle = |x\rangle + z|y \rangle$, taking both $z = 1$ and $z = i$. Alternatively, one could use the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity).

Note also that in general, $\langle u|A|v\rangle^* = \langle v|A^\dagger |u \rangle$ (where $z^*$ denotes the complex conjugate of $z$).

Now, if $A$ is semipositive, then $\langle v|A|v\rangle \geq 0$ implies that $\langle v|A|v\rangle$ is real for all $|v\rangle$. Thus,
$$
\langle v|A|v\rangle = \langle v|A|v\rangle^* = 
\langle v|A^\dagger|v\rangle. 
$$
Because this holds for all $|v\rangle$, we conclude that $A = A^\dagger$.